# MariaDB Python OperationalError: This feature is not implemented or disabled

Tags: mariadb, debian, python-3.10, mariadb-10.5

I've compiled and installed Python 3.10.9 (from .tar) and mariadb-c-connector (from official Github repo) on my Debian 11 (bullseye) machine.
I also installed: ufw, fail2ban, mariadb-server, mariadb-client.

Now if i install mariadb in my Python pipenv and run i got the error: `mariadb.OperationalError: This feature is not implemented or disabled`.

On my Manjaro it works fine. This is how i create a connection to the database.

```py
def connect(self):

    if self.conn:
        return

    # Connect to MariaDB Platform
    try:
        self.conn = mariadb.connect(
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password,
            host=self.host,
            port=self.port,
            database=self.database,
            reconnect=True,
        )
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        log.exception(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
        self.conn = None
        return
```

What i do wrong or what is missing?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

Output of `mariadb_config --cc_version --libs`

```bash
3.3.4
-L/usr/lib/mariadb/ -lmariadb
```

Output of `ldd /home/USER/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJEKT/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mariadb/_mariadb.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

```bash
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffa2eec000)
libmariadb.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadb.so.3 (0x00007f6911918000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6911743000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f691173d000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f691171b000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f6911688000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f6911394000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6911375000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6911988000)
```

Comment: Which version of Connector/C did you install? And what is the output of `python3.10 -c "import mariadb; print(mariadb.mariadbapi_version)"`

Comment: The newest 3.3. And the output is `10.5.18`

Comment: can you come up with a minimal complete script (with password obscured) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: what did you do to "install mariadb in my Python pipenv"?

Comment: Are you sure output is 10.5.18 and not 3.1.18 ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter 100%, copy + paste :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the check in source code:

```
#if MARIADB_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID > 30301
   if (mysql_optionsv(self->mysql, MARIADB_OPT_STATUS_CALLBACK, MrdbConnection_process_status_info, self))
      goto end;
#endif
```

It fails, since mysql_optionsv doesn't support the option `MARIADB_OPT_STATUS_CALLBACK` and returns error `CR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`.

Update (after more details were added to the original question):

So it looks like you built (installed) the mariadb module with the correct required Connector/C version (> 3.3.1) , however there is an older Connector/C version in your default library path `libmariadb.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadb.so.3` (which was likely installed with package [libmariadb-dev](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/libmariadb-dev/filelist))

Comment: First i installed MariaDB apt package, then the pipenv after that i got the error that the Connector/C is to old. So i update it and installed the pipenv again.

Did you now how i can remove the old Connector/C which is installed by the apt package?

Comment: I would try to remove mariadb-client first (apt-get remove)

Comment: I removed the mariadb-client, mariadb python package and reinstalled the self compiled Connector/C and than the python package from pipy. Same issue.

Comment: So I understand but how can i overwrite it with the new one? Or can say which one the lib should use?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a docker environment with python 3.11-slim and mariadb 10.11-rc. I also installed mariadb==1.1.5.post3.

I updated the MariaDB Connector/C using the [following instruction](https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql/connect/programming-languages/c/install/#Installation_via_Package_Repository_(Linux)).

Here's what I did in my Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc curl wget
RUN wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup
RUN chmod +x mariadb_repo_setup
RUN ./mariadb_repo_setup \ --mariadb-server-version="mariadb-10.6"
RUN apt install -y libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev
```

These commands helped me update the library to the new version.
In my connection code, I also replaced host with the name of the service from the `docker-compose.yml` file. In my case it will be `db`

```
from os import getenv

import mariadb

con = mariadb.connect(
    host='db',
    user=getenv('DB_USER', default=''),
    password=getenv('DB_PASS', default=''),
    database=getenv('DB_NAME', default=''),
)
cur = con.cursor()
```

I hope these commands help resolve the issue in your environment